# Unbinding eventListener when a $state (ui-router) is changed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, addeventlistener

In order to make different components to talk to each other, I'm using the `$emit` method within a method of a `service`

**Service code:**

```
this.triggerSelectedAction = function( actionName )
{
    $rootScope.$emit('action-changed', { actionName: actionName } );
};

this.triggerSelectedProject = function( projectName )
{
    $rootScope.$emit('project-changed', { projectName: projectName } );
};

this.triggerSelectedFile = function( fileName )
{
    $rootScope.$emit('file-changed', { fileName: fileName } );
};

this.subscribe = function( scope, cb )
{
    var eventHandler;
    eventHandler = $rootScope.$on('action-changed', cb);
    eventHandler = $rootScope.$on('project-changed', cb);
    eventHandler = $rootScope.$on('file-changed', cb);

    scope.$on( '$destroy', eventHandler );
};
```

Now let's assume that from somewhere inside the app I'm calling the `myService.triggerSelectedAction('doSomething');` and there is a specific `$state` (e.g toolsState) loaded at the time whose its `$onInit` method waits for this event to occur.

**toolsState Controller `$onInit` code:**

```
myService.subscribe($scope, function eventOccured(event, data) {
    if ( event.name === "action-changed" )              
        setEnvironment();
});

function setEnvironment() {
    // Attach an event listener to the select element
    document
        .getElementById("design-select")
        .addEventListener("change", projectSelectedEvent);
}
```

Now let's say that we change a state and go for example to the manageState which is also waiting for the same event to occur and has a similar `$onInit` code except the fact that it binds the `eventListener` to a different element.

**manageState Controller `$onInit` code:**

```
myService.subscribe($scope, function eventOccured(event, data) {
    if ( event.name === "action-changed" )              
        setEnvironment();
});

function setEnvironment() {
    // Attach an event listener to the select element
    document
        .getElementById("manage-select")
        .addEventListener("change", projectSelectedEvent);
}
```

In such a case, if the event is fired, everything works as expected except that I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` in the console that refers to the `toolsState` Controller line with the addEventListener method. It complains that it cannot find the element with `id` of `design-select` due to the state change.

To me, it seems that the `$scope` of the `toolsState` when the state changed and so its `myService.subscribe()` method still running.

Is there any way to get rid of this error.

Comment: In your subscribe function, why do you assign all three `$on` results to a single variable (`eventHandler`)? That's not how that works. You must assign a variable for each one, or your destroy method will only destroy the last one.

Comment: Hmm... you are right. So in order to provide multiple event handlers, in my subscribe method, I should also have multiple handler variables and `$destroy` events for all of them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever code passes a function or object to an API, one risks creating object references which will prevent garbage collection. This can result in memory leaks.

The `$on` method returns a function that can used to unbind the event handler:

```
this.subscribe = function( scope, cb )
{
    var deRegister = {};
    deRegister.ActionChanged = $rootScope.$on('action-changed', cb);
    deRegister.ProjectChanged = $rootScope.$on('project-changed', cb);
    deRegister.FileChanged = $rootScope.$on('file-changed', cb);

    scope.$on( '$destroy', function() {
        deRegister.ActionChanged();
        deRegister.ProjectChanged();
        deRegister.FileChanged();
        deRegister = null; //release deRegister object
        scope = null;      //release scope reference
        cb = null;         //release callback function reference
    ));
};
```

In addition to de-registering the event handlers, the code needs to release any object references created.